# VU meter web application

Tags: sound-card, audio-recording, web-application

I want a [VU meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VU_meter) web app which can detect sound levels from my system's mic. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

With Flash Actionscript 3 you can do it like so:

```
[
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); 
private function onEnterFrame(ev:Event):void
{
   activityLevel.setProgress(myMic.activityLevel, 100);
}   
]
```

Where `activityLevel` is a progressbar object and `myMic` is the mic. And add the event listener on the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want it?

It could be done very easily in Flash, just a couple lines of code. Don't know of any offhand that are already written for you.

Here's a very simple example, written in AS2 (Actionscript 2)

Create a box on the stage with the instance name 'box_mc'. Place this code on the stage.

```
myMic = Microphone.get();

_root.onEnterFrame = function() {
    box_mc._yscale = myMic.activityLevel;
}
```

The box should get bigger and smaller depending on the sound level.

Comment: want it to aid accessibility in browsing

Comment: any hints how it can be done in Flash?

Comment: edited my answer with a very simple example